# failed to send password reset link from flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

While sending forget password reset link from my flutter app, I'm getting success result but not getting the email on my email(not even in spam folder). I tried to send the reset link from the firebase console, from there also I got the success message but didn't get the email.

I've been stuck to this issue from almost 2 weeks, I've tried every possible solution from google.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest